# How to clear cache on Eclipse Android Emulator

Tags: android, caching

i was wondering if there is a fast way to clear cache on a running Eclipse Android Emulator, apart from shutting it down and starting it after.

For the time being, caching proved to be a major drawback for me, since am new to Android and it eventually lead me to wrong conclussions about my code...

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of cache are you referring to? You could always go into the settings / applications / app / 'clear cache' if there's any caching used by the app.

Comment: Hello, am referring to the fact that Android seems to keep the previous state of objects (e.g. intents) being created when an application is running. Am aware that this may be happening to reserve resources. However, this can be misleading, as it proved for  me, with my code working fine until an emulator restart, when my application eventually crushes on start.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can clear cache / data per application from settings (Applications -> manage applications). You can also uninstall your application from there which will cause everything to be cleared. This of course only clears data that your application is creating.

Answer (score 3):

Through the AVD manager when you 'start' a virtual device, check 'clear user data' before you click the launch button. This will clear the cache and reset the emulator back to its original state.